# the_excerpt didn't appear - woocommerce / wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

HMTL original rendered:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="row">
     <a href="http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/3-blog-post/">3 - Blog Post</a> 
     </div>
     <div class="row">                   
     <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-768x768.jpg 768w, http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal.jpg 900w" sizes="(max-width: 150px) 100vw, 150px" />  


    </div>
    </div>
```

HTML after setup_postdata( $post );

```
    <div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/3-blog-post/">
                3 - Blog Post            </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">                   
            <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal-768x768.jpg 768w, http://localhost/PHP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/imagem-principal.jpg 900w" sizes="(max-width: 150px) 100vw, 150px" />

Bem-vindo ao WordPress. Esse é o seu primeiro post. Edite-o ou exclua-o, e então comece a escrever!
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

Weird things:

[image]

The code:

```
 <div class="container">


    <div class="row">

<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach($recent_posts as $post) 
{
    ?><div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post['ID']); ?>">
                <?php echo $post['post_title']; ?>
            </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">                   
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <?php
            $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post['ID']);
            if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
              // Some string manipulation performed
            }
            echo $my_excerpt // Outputs the processed value to the page
            ?>

        </div>
    </div><?php 
}  
wp_reset_query();
?>

      </div>
</div>

</br>
</br>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach($recent_posts as $post) { ?>


            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post['ID']) ?>">
                  <?php echo $post['post_title'] ?>
                </a> 


              </div>
              <div class="row">                   

                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], 'thumbnail'); ?>

              </div>

              <div class="row">                   

                <?php
                $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post['ID']);
                if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                  // Some string manipulation performed
                }
                echo $my_excerpt // Outputs the processed value to the page
                ?>

              </div>
            </div>      


      <?php 
      }  
        wp_reset_query();
      ?>
      </div>

</div>
```

---

When I change the position of the code and remove title and thumbnail, the code works well:

```
  <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach($recent_posts as $post) { ?>


            <?php
            $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post['ID']);
            if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
              // Some string manipulation performed
            }
            echo $my_excerpt // Outputs the processed value to the page
            ?>

          </div>
        </div>      


  <?php 
  }  
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
```

I call the recent posts in my wordpress / woocommerce page, but when I call the excerpt, it didn't appear, title and thumbnail are ok. I have worked on it all day long, but I couldn't figure out what happen. When I change "echo $my_excerpt" with a simple word, it works. The problem should be when I put the content in a array. I had followed the documentation as you can see:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Examples
get_the_excerpt() can be used to retrieve and store the value in a variable, without outputting it to the page.

```
<?php
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
    // Some string manipulation performed
}
echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page
?>
```

My code:

```
      <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach($recent_posts as $post) { ?>


            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post['ID']) ?>">
                  <?php echo $post['post_title'] ?>
                </a> 


              </div>
              <div class="row">                   

                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], 'thumbnail'); ?>

                <?php
                $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                  // Some string manipulation performed
                }
                echo $my_excerpt // Outputs the processed value to the page
                ?>

              </div>
            </div>      


      <?php 
      }  
        wp_reset_query();
      ?>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your are not providing post id to get the excerpt like your are doing with your other functions. Since you are not using the formal loop mechanism of wordpress you need to give the id manually. See my answer.

Comment: write this after foreach starts setup_postdata( $post ); and it will work, just checked it.

Comment: A screenshot is fairly useless.  CSS or other oddities could be hiding your output.  Instead, do a "View Source" and show us the rendered HTML.

Comment: Well, after add setup_postdata($post) the excerpt appeared, but it brings the "Hello Word" post content in all of them. I'll post the rendered html. Just a minut.

Comment: No need / DO NOT USE `setup_postdata` - that does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a plenty of options, tests, feedbacks and research, I've found a way to make it.

Thank you everyone!

My final code:

```
<!-- Testando novo formato -->

<p class="display-4" style="text-align:center">Testando - Posts Recentes</p>


<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">


<?php
    query_posts( array('posts_per_page'=>3) );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

    <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; margin-bottom:3rem; margin-top:3rem;">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>">

                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      <?php
                        the_excerpt();
                      ?>
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>">Ler o post</a>
                </div>  
              </div>
    </div>

      <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query(); // resets main query
      ?>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So at the end you used the formal loop mechanism. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I have altered your code try using this one.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach($recent_posts as $post) 
{
    setup_postdata( $post ); // Edit: This will force wordpress to setup the data
    ?><div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post['ID']); ?>">
                <?php echo $post['post_title']; ?>
            </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">                   
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <?php
            $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post['ID']);
            if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
              // Some string manipulation performed
            }
            echo $my_excerpt // Outputs the processed value to the page
            ?>

        </div>
    </div><?php 
}  
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Try this. I have provided post id to your get the excerpt.

```
<?php
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post['ID']);
if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
  // Some string manipulation performed
}
echo $my_excerpt // Outputs the processed value to the page
?>
```

Comment: I changed the position of the code and remove title and thumbnail, this time, the excerpt apperared.

Comment: This is the problem. Change get_permalink to get_the_permalink and it will work

Comment: The code works fine, the problem I've seem is in the position. When I change the position, everything shows up

Comment: Can you please try the code that i have pasted once ? Wordpress has two type of function one return and the other echo. So please try it once. It will work.

Comment: I did. Nothing changed. Take a look in my edited post above.

Comment: See the edit. Doing this minor change after foreach start will make it work.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  As a side-note, there is no need for `post_setup_data` or `wp_reset_query` - the ENTIRE issue has to do with `get_the_excerpt` requires the post ID to be passed in.

Comment: @cale_b I don't know what to do. Someone commented something link "As u haven't used the default wordpress loop..." Do you know what it means? And how can I use the correct sintaxe?